# Trying to move a button to be on the right side of the screen. My right not the computers right

Tags: android, xml, button

In the xml I am trying to get the button to be on the right side. Here is my code.

```
   <TableRow>

    <Button
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:id="@+id/Button01"
        android:text="Sign in" />

   </TableRow>
```

When I delete the tableRow tags, the button goes the entire width of the screen.  I also played around with changing right to left and have still had no luck

Answer (score 5, accepted):

can you change the layout?

Try with:

```
<TableRow>
 <RelativeLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
   <Button
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/Button01"
    android:text="Sign in" />
 </RelativeLayout>
</TableRow>
```

Comment: Thanks, I had to play around with it a little but, but I got it to work

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me with in a Frame Layout:

`android:layout_gravity="right"`

for bottom and right try this:

```
android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
```

Answer (score 1):

You're missing width and height parameters for your `Button`. Add these to your button tag:

```
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

Also, `layout_gravity` will only apply in a `LinearLayout` or `FrameLayout`. If you're in a `RelativeLayout`, use `android:layout_alignParentRight="true"`